# cannot sent email with Laravel and gmail from localhost

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp

I want to sent mails from my laravel project with gmail smtp from localhost.

this is my .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp    
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com   
MAIL_PORT=587      
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

This is my config/mail.php file

```
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'myemail@gmail.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'My Name'),
    ],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    'username' => env('myemail@gmail.com'),

    'password' => env('password'),
```

When I run the script, it gives me the following error:

```
ErrorException in StreamBuffer.php line 94:
stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
```

Please note that I have already enabled the extension in my php.ini file.

Comment: seems that you dont have ssl cert installed on your local server. you can just use `aspmx.l.google.com` as host and port 25 with no encryption. tho  mail can only be sent to Gmail or G Suite users. but i think its fine since youre in dev env yet. see more details [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

your `.env` looks clean, but you need to double check if you change the account access for less secure apps.

Go to the [Less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) section then set to active.

Hope this work for you !!!

Answer (score 0):

just remove 
`MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls` from the .env file

and in your mail.php comment the following code line:

```
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'), //comment this line
```

Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: I have tried leaving the MAIL_ENCRYPTION=NULL and  'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', ''), but it did not work

Answer (score -2):

In your env just use:

**MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail**